# How the eq/eql/equal works whit list?

Tags: common-lisp, equality

Im a student and i need a little help, im doing a code to detect palindromes (words, phrases o sequences that reads de the same backwards as fowards) i have this code but the eql gives me always false and i dont know what is wrong

```
 (defun palindromo()
 (let ((a) (b '(itati)))
 (print "Ingrese una lista: ")
 (setq a(read))
 (reverse b )
 (if (eql '(a) '(b) )
       (print "Verdadero")
       (print "Falso"))
 );let
 );defun
```

this is a only a test version the original will work with any word or number

Comment: `eq/eql` result `t` for lists iff it is the same list, by reference, not by elements. in your case `equal` could do the trick. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node74.html

Comment: `(defun pal () (let ((a (read))) (equal a (reverse a))))`

Comment: `(eql '(a) '(b))` will always be wrong because these are two different constant literal lists.

Comment: FYI a variety of editors will help you manage the parenthesis ;) https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/editor-support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defun palindromo()
 (let ((a) (b '(itati)))
 (print "Ingrese una lista: ")
 (setq a(read))
 (reverse b )
 (if (eql '(a) '(b) )
       (print "Verdadero")
       (print "Falso"))
 );let
 );defun
```

Your code is mostly unreadable. You should spend some time to format and indent your code.

Problems:

```
(defun palindromo ()
  (let ((a)
        (b '(itati)))             ; literal data, don't modify that later
    (print "Ingrese una lista: ")

                                  ; needs a call to (finish-output) in portable code
                                  ;  to make sure that the output actually gets printed


    (setq a (read))
    (reverse b)                   ; the value of the expression is not used
                                  ; also: don't change literal data!
    (if (eql '(a) '(b) )          ; '(a) and '(b) are constant literal expressions
                                  ; a and b will never be evaluated
                                  ; thus the expression is always false
        (print "Verdadero")
        (print "Falso"))))
```

**To Do:**

- make sure that `a` and `b` get evaluated for comparison
- use `EQUAL` as a test
- use the result of `(reverse b)`
- don't set `b` to a literal constant
- make sure output appears

Comment: Thank you so much, i will try that